# BeautifulSoup grabbing text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm a bit confused as to how to get something with BeautifulSoup, the html that I'm trying to grab looks like this:

```
<div class="txt-block"> 
    <h4 class="inline">Gross:</h4> 
    $408,992,272
</div>
```

I want to grab the dollar number.
So far I have this, but it doesn't quite get me what I want.

```
gross = data.findAll('h4',class_='inline')
```

Data is my beautifulsoup object and there are also multiple instances of the `h4` tag, `class_=inline`

I'm ok with grabbing all of the `h4` tags as long as I can get the number in there also, then I can just regex it.

Comment: Can you make sure that the html is complete and correct?

Comment: looks like dollar number is out of h4 tag. you may need to first grab parent of both h4 tag and dollar number and start from there. What is the structure of parent element of dollar number?

Comment: Ah gotcha, the parent is ```<div class="txt-block">
    <h4 class="inline">Gross:</h4>        $408,992,272        ``` which I was able to get, I should be able to take it from here. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the dollar amount, find_all the text from the *txt-block* *div* setting *recursive=False* so you don't get any text from its children and strip any whitespace:

```
In [27]:h = """<div class="txt-block">
                   <h4 class="inline">Gross:</h4>
                    $408,992,272
               </div>"""

In [28]: soup = BeautifulSoup(h,"lxml")

In [29]: div = soup.find("div",class_="txt-block")

In [30]: "".join(div.find_all(text=True, recursive=False)).strip()
Out[30]: '$408,992,272'
```

Or if you know it is the always the last item element, you could use:

```
In [40]: div.contents[-1].strip()
Out[40]: '$408,992,272'
```